# Spring hides RuntimeException thrown by a @Transactional method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, transactions, spring-data-jpa

As part of my code a `@Transactional` annotated method. In some scenarios, the method throws a custom exception an performs a rollback. Whenever this happens the method-call results in a `TransactionSystemException` and no way to get the original custom-exception (it's not the root cause of the Exception).

Can I somehow get access to the original exception thrown by my method?
Can I stop spring from throwing the TransactionSystemException, but still rollback?

```
@Transactional
public Association create(Long accountId) {
    // if association already exists, throw exception
    throw new ErrorInfoException(ErrorInfo.duplicateAssociation(accountId).info("This Association already exists").build());
}
```

Comment: can you add the transactional method where you throw those custom exceptions?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski i edited down one of the methods. they are all pretty simple

Comment: how do you try to retrieve the root / original exception from the TransactionSystemException?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you manage exceptions outside of that method, but you would need to catch the `TransactionSystemException` and then, in your case invoke the `getApplicationException()` as your custom exception should first on the stack:

> Return the application exception that was thrown before this
>   transaction exception, if any.

If for some reason there are some more exceptions in-between then go for the `getOriginalException()` which according to the spec should:

> Return the exception that was the first to be thrown within the failed
>   transaction: i.e. the application exception, if any, or the
>   TransactionSystemException's own cause.

If you use the `getCause` method of the Exception then that may not be proper way in this case.

Comment: unfortunately the ApplicationException is null and the OriginalException is only the "javax.persistence.RollbackException" that is already the cause. it seems my custom exception is gone.